# Can I write an expression that enters the quaternion space without expressing the variables associated?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, quaternions

First of all, forgive my little knowledge on the subject.

I can enter the complex space by just using an expression only having real numbers, for example:

```
f(x)= (-1)^x
```

as [f(x)= (-1)^x - Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3D%20%28-1%29%5Ex) proves. I didn't express anything dependent on the imaginary unit i.

Can I similarly enter the quaternion space, just by using real or complex numbers on the expression? I mean to not use j and k.

Comment: How do you define $b^x$ where $b,x$ are positive real numbers (You may suppose $b>1$)?

And now. How do you define $b^x$ where $b<0$ in the real numbers?

For example, in the real numbers $(-1)^{1/2}$ is not defined. Of course we can define $(-1)^{1/2}$ as $i$, an imaginary number. Like that, it's possible that you are using implicitly $i$.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper: Did you enter the link I provided? If you entered you would understand just looking to the graphics.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper: My question is similar. Can I define the things the same way to can enter the quaternion space?

Comment: I entered. That's why I am asking you this. Without giving a clear definition of what you are trying to do, we can't do anything (Or can do everything without formality).

Comment: We can define $f(z)=1/z$ if $z\neq 0$ and $f(z)=j$ if $z=0$.
It wouldn't be continuous, but when you evaluate it at $0$ you get $j$.
And if you express it like $f(z)$ you can't see the $j$ we wrote in the definition.
That's what happens. When you define $(-1)^x$ the $i$ is in the definition.

Comment: Looking here in the definition of complex powers: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html
you get that if $a<0$, then $arg(a)=\pi$ and $a^c=|a|^c e^{ic\pi}$. But that's the definition, in real analysis you don't use things like $(-1)^{x}$.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper: If I specify 
$f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) \rightarrow \mathbb{H},$ 

or

$f(z), z \in \mathbb{C}, f(z) \rightarrow \mathbb{H},$

can I get some $f(x)$ or some $f(z)$ that will have non-zero coefficients on $j$ or $k$?

Comment: The one I said has that property. $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ given by $f(x)=1/x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $j$ otherwise.

Comment: You used a $j$ in the expression. The goal was to not use any variable outside the complex space.

Comment: You asked:
"If I specify $f(x),x∈R,f(x)→H, or f(z),z∈C,f(z)→H$, can I get some $f(x)$ or some $f(z)$ that will have non-zero coefficients on $j$ or $k$?"

If you want to give the answers some restrictions you should state them there. Since the restrictions you want to give the answer are not even well defined I thought you gave up on that and changed it to some function like the one there.

Comment: A workaround for that which shows your restriction is absurd.

From set theory we have that $(\mathbb{H}-\mathbb{R})^\mathbb{R}$ is not empty, so let $f\in (\mathbb{H}-\mathbb{R})^\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is the function you want. Furthermore, I have not used any variable outside the complex field.

Comment: I do not understand your notation. What means $f \in (\mathbb{H} - \mathbb{H})^\mathbb{R}$ ? I can understand that what is inside the parentheses are all numbers belonging to the H set that are not part of the R set, but the exponent is a thing I can not grasp its meaning.

Comment: In set theory, $(\mathbb{H}-\mathbb{R})^\mathbb{R}$means "The set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{H}-\mathbb{R}$". It's not as heavy as it seems.

Answer (score 2):

A function is well defined only if we specify the **Domain** and the **Codomain**. So, if we write simply $f(x)=(-1)^x$ the function is ill-defined. We have to specify if we want a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ or $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ or $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $, and all these are different functions.

Look well at the page you have linked. When WA gives the ''Properties as a real function'' write that The Domain and the Codomain are the empty set. This means that such a function ( reals to reals) is not defined.

Obviously you can define a function that has $\mathbb{R}$ as Domain and Codomain on the quaternions, but it is a matter of definition.

Answer (score 0):

From set theory we have that $(\mathbb{H}-\mathbb{R})^\mathbb{R}$ is not empty, so let $f\in (\mathbb{H}-\mathbb{R})^\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is the function you want. Furthermore, I have not used any variable outside the complex field.

By the way, any function you find there, even if you don't use any variable outside the complex fields may be restated like this.

Let's suppose that for some $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=a+bi+cj+dk$ and define $f_2(w)=f(w)$ if $w=x$ and $f_2(w)=a+bi+cj+dk$ otherwise. Then $f_2=f$ and even if I didn't use any variable outside the complex field when defining $f$, I did when defining $f_2$.

Without redefining your restriction "not using any variable outside the complex field" in a formal, exact, and non-ambiguous way, this is not a mathematical question.